# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.CardScrollView"

Tags: android-notifications, wear-os

I am trying to build my custom notification and I got everything working but my layout is cut-off in the stream-card. Doesn't seem like it manages to display my whole custom layout inside the stream card even though I only use about 50% of the screen height. But I see other custom layouts like the Sports cards from Google Now that are larger than mine.

So I tried to wrap my RelativeLayout in a CardScrollView (not sure it will help though) but when I run that code the Wear device crashes with:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo ...

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.CardScrollView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.apk"],nativeLibrary...
```

My gradle file looks like this:

```
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 compile project(':common')
 compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
}
```

I am really at a loss on how to fix this error, I have tried cleaning the project and reinstalling the app but the error is still there. Anyone have successfully used these layouts?

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/layouts.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### CardScrollView:

System cannot find such class like `android.view.CardScrollView` because.. there is no such class.
According to the wearable-support documentation the `CardScrollView` is in the `android.support.wearable.view` package and NOT in `android.view`.

You you need to type `android.support.wearable.view.CardScrollView` in order to use this view.

### Custom content height:

You can provide a height for your custom content in notification using one of these methods:
[`setCustomContentHeight(int height)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.WearableExtender.html#setCustomContentHeight(int))
or
[`setCustomSizePreset(int sizePreset)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.WearableExtender.html#setCustomSizePreset(int))

With `setCustomContentHeight` you just need to specify the size in pixels, but in `setCustomSizePreset` you need to use one of the predefined presets:

- [`WearableExtender.SIZE_DEFAULT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.WearableExtender.html#SIZE_DEFAULT)
- [`WearableExtender.SIZE_FULL_SCREEN`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.WearableExtender.html#SIZE_FULL_SCREEN)
- [`WearableExtender.SIZE_LARGE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.WearableExtender.html#SIZE_LARGE)
- [`WearableExtender.SIZE_MEDIUM`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.WearableExtender.html#SIZE_MEDIUM)
- [`WearableExtender.SIZE_SMALL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.WearableExtender.html#SIZE_SMALL)
- [`WearableExtender.SIZE_XSMALL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.WearableExtender.html#SIZE_XSMALL)

BTW. I doubt that you can use a scrollable layout inside your custom card layout.

Comment: Please take all my money! Thanks for a brilliant answer that solved all my issues.